# Cost forecast Azure vs pricing tier costs of SQL database

Tags: azure

I have an SQL database on Azure with „Basic“ pricing tier (i.e. 5 DTUS and 2 GB storage) for a price of 7.38 CHF per month.
However, when I go to my subscription, in the „Overview“ section there is a plot that shows the spending rate and a forecast that shows that the costs will be 9.80 CHF.
Until now I was under the assumption that the costs would not change (unless I change the pricing tier of course). What did I miss? How can I more accurately know the costs in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up the price calculator and enter everything you will be using for an estimate. Refer to the detailed bill for what you are missing, possibly some network transfer. This type of usage based cloud billing is heavy on the "microtransactions", very unlikely that one product would be the entire bill. Ask Azure billing support for detailed help.

Realize that this is not a large amount of spend. Less than [2 Big Mac sandwiches](https://www.economist.com/news/2020/07/15/the-big-mac-index), if I got the exchange rate correct. Divide this by your hourly wage, or the project's budget, to get some idea of how much time is worth spending here. If you are learning on a small budget, fine, but public cloud can be expensive with an difficult to understand bill.